# Trying to submit a form in my popup and get value that was submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

The goal of this code is to get a user input from a simple form in my Chrome extension pop up. When the user submits the form, I want the value in that `input` field to be added to the array of myNames.

In `popup.html`

```
  <form class="my-form">
    <input placeholder="Enter a name" class="name-to-submit"></input>
    <a href="#" class="primary button submit">Add Name</a>
  </form>
```

In popup.js

```
    var newName = $('.name-to-submit').val();
    if ($('.submit').click() && newName !== "") {
    ... do some stuff
    }
```

My problem is that newName is always coming through as `""` and I can't figure out why...

Should I change my `anchor tag` to a `button` or an `input` with `type=submit`?

Or do something else?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a click event tied to your anchor? That should set it off after the text has been typed in.

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
 var newName = $('.name-to-submit').val();
alert(newName);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HARR2/

EDIT: if you want to fire this event when the user hits enter(on form submit)

```
$(".my-form").submit(function(){
 var newName = $('.name-to-submit').val();
alert(newName);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HARR2/2/

Comment: What if I wanted to do this when the user types something in the input box and presses enter, so basically, on form submit?

Comment: @ZackShapiro
$(".my-form").submit(function(){
 var newName = $('.name-to-submit').val();
alert(newName);
});
http://jsfiddle.net/HARR2/2/

Answer (score 0):

I would always declare the type attribute of an input element.  Should your name input element have the attribute type="text"?

Comment: I added it after I asked this question